# Why is my expression not being returned in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, methods, return, substring

I have the following code:

```
def foo(str: String, key: Char) : String = {

  breakable{
    for(it <- 0 until str.length){
      if(str.charAt(it) != key){
        str.slice(0, it) + str.slice(it+1, str.length)
        break
      }
    }
  }
  str
}
```

However, `str.slice(0, it) + str.slice(it+1, str.length)` is never returned, only str.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: In scala if there is not return keyword last sentence will be returned. Since last sentence is `str` then this value will be returned. You are not changing `str` in any way in your code.

Comment: seems you try to find some illegal symbol and drop it first occurrence from string, you can do it simply by replaceFirst method: `str.replaceFirst(key.toString, "")`

Comment: It's more complicated than that, I just posted the essential parts to the question. I can't post the rest for plagiarism reasons. All I need is to be able to return ```str.slice(0, it) + str.slice(it+1, str.length)``` when the if statement is true.

Comment: `if(){v}` without a `else` returns a `Unit`, whatever is the type of `v`. This code has several code smells.

Comment: Since you said this is an assignment, it would be worth mentioning what are you are and aren't allowed to do.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be done in two parts. First you find the index of this char in string (if it exists). Now, if you find the index, you return the sliced string otherwise return the original string.

I am assuming you can not use some of the String methods to directly do this...

If you are using Scala 2.13

```scala
def foo(string: String, key: Char): String = {
  val indexOption =
    string
      .lazyZip(LazyList.from(0))
      .find({ case (c, i) => c == key })
      .map({ case (c, i) => i })

  indexOption
    .map(index => string.slice(0, index) + string.slice(index + 1, string.length))
    .getOrElse(string)
}
```

Or, if you are using Scala 2.12,

```
def foo(string: String, key: Char): String = {
  val indexOption =
    string
      .toStream
      .zipWithIndex
      .find({ case (c, i) => c == key })
      .map({ case (c, i) => i })

  indexOption
    .map(index => string.slice(0, index) + string.slice(index + 1, string.length))
    .getOrElse(string)
}
```

Comment: `find` + `map` is basically `collectFirst`. Also, I guess it would be better to just use `iterator.zipWithIndex` which is compatible with both versions of **Scala** _(and with `2.11` too)_.

Answer (score -1):

The str is a val and it is not updated in your operations... your are ignoring the result of that string addition

pretty much your code is exactly the same as:

```
def foo(str: String, key: Char) : String = str
```

try using a var if you want to keep updating the result, or use other methods over the string to achieve the same without var... with the var it could be something like this:

```
import util.control.Breaks._
def foo(str: String, key: Char) : String = {
  var bar = str
  breakable {
    for(it <- 0 until str.length){
      if(str.charAt(it) != key){
        bar = str.slice(0, it) + str.slice(it+1, str.length)
      break
     }
    }
  }
  bar 
}
```

edit:
As you commented you must not use var on your assignment, consider the foldLeft to sort out the same problem:

```
def foo(str: String, key: Char): String = {
  string
    .foldLeft("") {
      case (acc, c) =>
        if(c == key) acc
        else acc + c
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use 'var' as a rule for this assignment

Comment: Ok, that's another thing... I just tried to explain what was wrong on your approach... you probably want to try using recursive approach to do this, or using folds but breakable will returned you a Unit as result, so you will need to modify something

Comment: as I see this is an assignment, I would say for you to look into foldLeft or foldRight and you should be fine... I guess you were never requested to use breakable

Comment: May the downvoter provide some feedback about what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: Problem 1 - if we call `foo("1234321", '3')`, the non-var implementation will return `12421` where as it should have been `124321`. Problem 2 - String concatenation is costly (`O(n)`), so that `acc + c` while folding on the string is really bad. this solution is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Starts to feel that to answer why didn't work the code now I am down voted for things totally out the scope of the question. I may update it when I have time for it, but it would be good to have the whole question cause I only see what the code sample tries to do, not what we must solve.

Comment: my single downvote is because the non-var solution is not correct at all (even your two solutions give totally different answers). The second issue string of concatenation is still very serious but since you seem like a new contributed to our Scala community, I would not have down-voted solely for that.

Comment: Also, your motivation for contribution should not be "to be right", we are all here to learn, we all can be wrong, we all have room to improve. All of us can overlook small things sometimes, so mutual feedback helps

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh A very costly operation is not always bad and in any case, it should be more of a comment instead of a downvote. And considering that this is just for an assignment _(explicitly stated by OP)_ then such arguments are even more meaningless. The wrong implementation does merit a down vote though _(however please the next time you downvote leave your feedback right away)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez My downvote is the second one, which was added after the comment. I am totally unrelated to both the mysterious owner and mysterious reason of first downvote.